# Array argument must be ByRef

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, pass-by-reference

What am I doing wrong here?

```
Sub Main()

Dim patients() As String

' Some code to populate the patients array, works fine

CalculateScores (patients) ' Array argument must be ByRef compile error

End Sub



Sub CalculateScores(patients As String)

End Sub
```

If I change patients to a variant array in Main and the parameters of CalculateScores it works fine but I can't see the logic of not being able to pass a string. By default it is ByRef so I know I'm missing something.

I can use a variant sure, but it feels hacky.

Comment: The `patients` parameter isn't an array for starters.

Comment: If that's a typo in the question, you just need to [remove the parens](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/1179/procedure-calls/3818/this-is-confusing-why-not-just-always-use-parentheses) from the `CalculateScores` call: `CalculateScores patients`

Comment: To clarify what @Comintern said, the `CalculateScores` is expecting a real String, not an array of strings.

Comment: Bingo. CalculateScores(patients() As String) and calling the sub without parameters did the trick, thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this:

```
DoSomething (expression)
```

You're forcing `expression` to be evaluated *as a value*, and passed `ByVal`, **regardless of whether the parameter explicitly says it's passed ByRef**. While that has more or less no impact most of the time, it bites you in the rear end when you try to pass an array or an object reference.

Drop the parentheses.

```
DoSomething expression
```

---

Now, there are other problems with your code: You're passing an array of strings into a `String` parameter; that can't work. Make the parameter an array or a `Variant`, and I'd suggest marking the parameter explicitly as `ByRef`, for clarity.

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify for others - my parameter should have been a string() not a string, as Mat's Mug suggests.