# VBA: type mismatch -- how to pass ADODB.Recordset object to subroutine?

Tags: vba, ado, adodb

I encountered a type mismatch error when passing a `ADODB.Recordset` object to a subroutine. See the code nugget below.

```
Sub CreateRS()
    Dim oCONN As ADODB.Connection
    Dim oRS As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strConn As String

    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                "Data Source=" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
                "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;"";"
    Set oCONN = New ADODB.Connection
    oCONN.Open strConn

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM mytable"
    Set oRS = New ADODB.Recordset
    oRS.Open strSQL, oCONN

    ' type mismatch error for the next statement
    ProcessRS (oRS)
End Sub

Sub ProcessRS(ByRef RS As ADODB.Recordset)
    ....
End Sub
```

Did quite a bit of searches, yet didn't find a correct answer. Can anyone point out what is the right syntax to use here? Thanks!

Comment: Just before calling the command `ProcessRS (oRS)`, can you try a `Debug.Print TypeName(oRS)` and tell us what it prints? Also, parameters are passed to `Sub` routines with brackets only if using the old method `Call myMacro(myParameter)`. Now it's rather used `myMacro myParameter`, try that one too after making sure the type name of the parameter is correctly declared.

Comment: Did you try using the call keyword  pass the variable? I seem to remember having this issue a while back and that was the solve.

so use Call ProcessRS (oRS)

Comment: Just remove parentheses `ProcessRS oRS`. In that case parentheses mean evaluation of expression. You need parentheses for functions call syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array argument must be ByRef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42093387/array-argument-must-be-byref).  Although the question is *slightly* different (giving a compile error), the answer will explain your issue.

Comment: @omegastripes thanks, your comment solved my problem. If you can post it below, I will set it as the answer...